# Remove collation from all database columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database where the collation is set on it. However I am running into problems as the collation on some columns in the database varies from the database collation.

I would like to remove collation from the columns and use the collation set on the database.

I am working with SQL Server 2012.

How can I do this? Can a script do this?

Answer (score 14):

With this script here, you can find all columns that don't match the database default:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseCollation VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
    @DatabaseCollation = collation_name 
FROM 
    sys.databases
WHERE 
    database_id = DB_ID()

SELECT 
    @DatabaseCollation 'Default database collation'

SELECT 
    t.Name 'Table Name',
    c.name 'Col Name',
    ty.name 'Type Name',
    c.max_length,
    c.collation_name,
    c.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id    
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND 
    c.collation_name <> @DatabaseCollation
```

For each of those columns, you can then execute this simple command to change their collation to be the database default:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

If you really really want, you could probably also combine the two - use a cursor on the `SELECT` statement from the first script and then iterate over the results and execute the second statement for each column found - I typically prefer to do this manually, to be more aware of what I'm doing (and how much I'm changing):

Comment: One thing to note: you cannot change the collation of a column that is part of an index or constraint. You will need to drop the index/constraint before being able to change the collation - which requires a bit more scripting.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code for changing the database collation, it will change the collation of whole database but not of single object.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + SYSOBJECTS.Name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + SYSCOLUMNS.Name + ' ' + 
SYSTYPES.name + '(' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,SYSCOLUMNS.length)) + ') ' + ' COLLATE [Replace Actual Collation]' + CASE ISNULLABLE WHEN 0 THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'NULL' End +
CHAR(13) + ' GO'
FROM SYSCOLUMNS , SYSOBJECTS , SYSTYPES
WHERE SYSCOLUMNS.ID = SYSOBJECTS.ID
AND SYSOBJECTS.TYPE = 'U'
AND SYSTYPES.Xtype = SYSCOLUMNS.xtype
AND SYSCOLUMNS.COLLATION IS NOT NULL
GO
```

I've taken the code from the following link.

http://samsudeenb.blogspot.com/2007/01/changing-database-collation.html